# boost:: Mac vs Linux compiling question

Tags: regex, linux, macos, boost

Odd question that is leading to more premature greying.

I have code that compiles on both a Macintosh environment (OSX 10.6) using codeworks and compiles on linux machine (Ubuntu) again using the same environment of codeworks. The application processes an XML file using boost::regex but oddly enough using the same test file, the output files are ever so slightly different.

Is this normal? The code is absolutely identical. On the macintosh I'm using Boost v1.44 but on the linux box I'm using v1.38.

Any wisdom you can part with, will bring you tons of positive karma.

Thanks,
david s.

Answer (score 2):

It could be due to the bugfixes and/or modifications to the Boost framework between your 2 versions. Either that, or your compiler is doing something incorrectly (which is highly unlikely).

Try compiling with the same Boost versions and see if the results are the same?